# Package Length (mils) and Propagation Delay(ps/Inch) data for DDR3 and FPGA

Tags: fpga, ddr3

I need to provide below data to my software team for DDR testing.

1.Package Length(Mils)

2.Propagation Delay(Ps/inch)

We are using MT41K256M 16HA-125 DDR3 chip with ZYNQ 7045 FFG FPGA.

I am unable to find the above mentioned in the datasheet.

EDIT:-
We are using a custom board of the ZYNQ 7045 FFG package and trying to do an Ethernet throughput test based on xapp1026. We followed all the configuration settings required in ZYNQ and also in PC as mentioned in xapp1026. But our applications in ARM are getting hanged either in pre-fetch abort or data abort and the iperf application in PC is not receiving any further data. But when we try the same on the Xilinx ZC706 evaluation board it is working fine and getting the expected speeds without any interruption. Source files and settings used on both (custom and Xilinx) hardware are the same.

One observation is this problem is coming only when we are trying to do data transfer at a higher data rate. For normal speeds, it is working fine.

The Ethernet IC chipset used in our custom board is Marvell 88E1512. The DDR IC chipset used in our custom board is MT41K256M 16HA-125.

Can we debug anything by observing the XML file (the one in system_hw_platform folder) that is generated when creating the project in the ISE tool? Please throw some light on this issue which will help us in debugging.

They need the above data for Board Delay Calculation Table

[image]

Comment: Propagation delay depends on your layout, so we can't tell you that. Package length is either 10mm, 12mm or 9mm depending on the RAM package you've selected

Comment: Can you tell us why they need this information? This gives us more context which will give you higher quality answers. I can't understand why a software team would need to know the package length of a device. Are you sure this is actually what they want? Also, propagation delay is a function of the PCB layout, not the device (the assumption is that any timing diagrams in a datasheet show timings at the pins of the device). I suspect that your team is trying to write a Timing Constraints. Is this the case?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: The propagation delay for most standard PCBs is 160 ps / inch (surface) to about 175 ps / inch (inner layers).

Comment: What about the package length ? Will it be present on the datasheet of DDR or Zynq?

Comment: @Puffafish I am using this particular DDR3 chip MT41K256M 16HA-125. How can I decide about package length?

Comment: Package length seems to be immaterial. Bond wire length would be more important.

Comment: @PeterSmith In the Pic I have attached, it is expecting the "Package Length"

Comment: I understand what has been asked for; I am questioning why they believe the package length has anything to do with propagation delay (It doesn't).

Comment: @PeterSmith, The "Package Length" value is of FPGA or the DDR?

Comment: I have just realised that 'package length' may well refer to the internal bond wire length. Have you considered looking at the simulation models? You can find these at Micron under Support.